# Orientation Problem in Camera

Tags: android

hi i am an android developer.

i am making a camera application in android.
i have a sony Experia X10. version 2.1
i am launching a hardware camera. but when the
preview is start it come with noise in portrait mode or 90 degree anti
clockwise
but in landscape it comes better.

but if i checked same appliction in sony Experia X8. version 2.1
preview comes good in both mode landscape or portrait.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the original of this post from: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/24dfa452ffc0e049

There's no way to do this on many current devices, including the G1 and Droid. Take a look at the relevant bug report here:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1193

Also see a comment from one of the Android engineers (Dave) here:

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/24dfa452ffc0e049